# Determining a joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that I have a continuous random variable $X$ whose probability density function is denoted $f_X(x)$. If I have a function $U$ of $X$, I know that this defines a new random variable $Y=U(X)$.

In the case where the function $U$ is strictly increasing or decreasing I can determine the probability density of $Y$ from

$$
f_Y(y) = f_X(W(y)) \left|\frac{d}{dy}W(y)\right|
$$

where $W$ is the inverse function of $U$. My question is: is there a straightforward way in this case to determine the joint density function $f_{X,Y}(x, y)$? In other words: when there is a known (and nice) functional dependence between random variables, is there a way to know the form of their joint distribution?

As an example, let $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and let $Y = U(X)=-\exp(-\gamma X)$. Obviously, we know the form of $f_X(x)$ and we can compute $f_Y(y)$. But how can I determine the form of $f_{X,Y}(x, y)$?

Comment: $Y$ is completely determined by $X$, so conditional on $X$, $Y$ has a degenerate distribution. Example in multivariate normal distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Degenerate_case

Answer (score 1):

You would use: $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X}(x) f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = f_X(x)~\delta{(y+\exp(-\gamma x))}$

Because there is a 1:1 determinacy between $x$ and $y$